# Hibernate One To Many Mapping With Fixed Values

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I don't have a lot of experience with database design and i try to understand the general logic behind it with using an ORM like hibernate. I have two tables user and languages. User could know one or more languages so there is a one to many relation between two tables. But i have a fixed length of languages English , Spanish and French for example. As i understand with each new user instance persisted there will be duplicate entries in the language table with a foreign key of that person. Is there a way to prevent this duplicate entries ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is a little confused. You can map a `OneToMany` relationship using a `Foreign Key`, and there are good database reasons to do so, though generally [a JPA provider recommends against it](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-mapping-association). However, you are describing a `ManyToMany` relationship. A `User` will (or could) have **many** `Languages`. A `Language` will have **many** `Users`. When you create a many to many relationship with annotations:

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Language> languages;
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Language {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
```

The JPA provider will create an association or `Join Table`, with an id from each `Entity` in it:

```
create table Person_Language (Person_id bigint not null, languages_id bigint not null)
```

When you create a language, an entry will be put in the language table. When you create a user, an entry will be put into the user table. When you add a language to a person's `languages` then an entry will be put into the `Join Table`.

```
insert into Person_Language (Person_id, languages_id) values (?, ?)
```

There will be only unique combinations of `Person_id` and `languages_id` in the join table, and so the database will be well normalized. You would not be able to assign a language to multiple users using a `Foreign Key` in the `Language` entity for the reason you pointed out: there would be only one foreign key column for any given language.